# Clustered static map from Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, react-native-map-clustering

I'm trying to extract static maps using Mapbox's [Static Images API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/static-images). The goal is to embed these images into an HTML page/email etc. Here is a sample that I was able to generate successfully which is at zoom level 13 using custom styles I built on Mapbox Studio:

[image: EV NY]

However, I need a similar static map that could be similarly extracted from Mapox's Static Image API in a clustered view when zoomed out. I've found that Mapbox doesn't support clustering via Mapbox studio (styles) so I'm running out of options on how to achieve this. I was able to come up with the below-clustered view (screenshot) using Html/javascript but then again, can't seem to figure how to retrieve a static image out of it:

[image]

Static Image API playground - https://docs.mapbox.com/playground/static/

Comment: Is the data you want to cluster being added to the map as a GeoJSON? I don’t know that this is currently possible with the Static Images API, but would like to better understand your current approach before I say anything definitive.

Comment: Very unique problem statement; would need more details.

Comment: @riastrad - Yes, its a GeoJSON data that I had uploaded via Mapbox studio.